# React: Realtime rendering Axios return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

hope you're well. I've been working on a company list component. I am having a problem with updating it in real time, because the axios call I'm sending to 'getById' after it renders is returning only a promise and not the actual data that it is supposed to and I don't have any idea as to why. So when I push the so called new company that I've just added into the array, which is in state, it is only pushing a promise into the array and not the actual *Company*. I don't have any idea why this is. What the code is supposed to be doing, is it is supposed to be putting the new company into the database, returning the success result, and then I'm using the item from that to make a fresh get call to the axios DB which is supposed to be returning the information I just entered so that I can then insert it into the same array in state that is within the list that is rendered in the company list. However, as I mentioned, only the promise is coming up for some reason.

At one point I was able to get this working, but I did that by essentially calling, 'componentDidMount' after the promise was pushed into the call back clause of the setState funciton of the push function - which was essentially causing the entire component to re-render. I'm a fairly new coder, but my understanding is is that that is a fairly unconventional way to code something, and contrary to good coding methodologies. I believe I should be able to push it into state, and then have it change automatically. I have attached the relevant code below for you to examine. If you believe you need more please let me know. If someone could please tell me why I am getting this weird promise instead of the proper response object, so that I can then insert that into state, I would greatly appreciate it. I've attached some images below the code snippets that I hope will be helpful in providing an answer. I have also left brief descriptions of what they are.
:

```
class Companies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Companies: [],
      formData: { label: "", value: 0 },
    };
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getListCompanies();
  };
  getListCompanies = () => {
    getAll().then(this.listOfCompaniesSuccess);
  };
  listOfCompaniesSuccess = (config) => {
    let companyList = config.items;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        Companies: companyList,
      };
    });
  };
  onCompListError = (errResponse) => {
    _logger(errResponse);
  };
  mapCompanies = (Companies) => (
    <CompaniesList Companies={Companies} remove={remove} />
  );
  handleSubmit = (values) => {
    if (values.companyName === "PPP") {
      this.toastError();
      //THIS IS FOR TESTING.
    } else {
      add(values)
        .getById(values.item) //I HAVE TRIED IN TWO DIFFERENT PLACES TO GET THE NEW COMPANY IN. HERE
        .then(this.newCompanyPush)
        .then(this.toastSuccess)
        .catch(this.toastError);
    }
  };
//THIS CODE RIGHT HERE IS THE CODE CAUSING THE ISSUE.
  newCompanyPush = (response) => {
    let newCompany = getById(response.item); // THIS IS THE OTHER PLACE I HAVE TRIED.
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newCompanyList = [...prevState.Companies];
      newCompanyList.push(newCompany);
      return {
        Companies: newCompanyList,
      };
    });
  };

  toastSuccess = () => {
    toast.success("Success", {
      closeOnClick: true,
      position: "top-right",
    });
  };
  toastError = (number) => {
    toast.error(`Error, index is ${number}`, {
      closeOnClick: true,
      position: "top-center",
    });
  };
```

This is the axios call I am using.

```
const getById = (id) => {
  const config = {
    method: "GET",
    url: companyUrls + id,
    withCredentials: true,
    crossdomain: true,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  };

  return axios(config).then(onGlobalSuccess).catch(onGlobalError);
};
```

[image: After the promise is pushed into the array, this is what it looks like. Which is I guess good news because something is actually rendering in real time.]
After the promise is pushed into the array, this is what it looks like. Which is I guess good news because something is actually rendering in real time.

[image]
This is the 'promise' that is being pushed into the array. Please note, when I make the same call in post-man, I get an entirely different response, see below.

[image]
This is the outcome I get in postman, when I test the call.

Comment: `newCompanyPush = async (response) => {` and then `let newCompany = await getById(response.item);`

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. I would give you ten upvotes if I could. You saved the day.